Algorithm to Minimize Time to Complete All Endings in a Multi-Branch Game with Limited Save Points
In a multi-branch game, there are  possible endings. You can think of it as a directed tree with  leaf nodes, where each edge has a weight of 1. Instead of playing through the entire game to reach all possible endings, which is time-consuming, you have  save points. What algorithm can maximize the use of these  save points to complete all endings in the shortest possible time?
I once considered using a greedy algorithm, calculating the gain-cost ratio for each point. However, I found that the order in which the points are established affects each other. If an upstream save point is established first, the cost of establishing downstream save points decreases, but the additional gain from them also becomes smaller. This made me doubt the correctness of the greedy algorithm. And I want to know if there is a better algorithm.
Let me provide an example. Assume we have a tree structure as follows:
A————B————C
     |
     B1——-C1————D
          |
          C2————D1

If we don't use any save points, the path from A to C costs 2 steps. After reaching C, we would need to return to A. The path from A to D costs 4 steps, and the path from A to D1 costs 5 steps. Therefore, the total cost is:2(A to C)+4(A to D)+5(A to D1)=11
However, if we have a save point at B, the cost to set the save point is 1 step (since you need to move from A to B). From there, we can start again at B and visit C, D, and D1. The total cost is reduced to:1(A to B)+1(B to C)+3(B to D)+4(B to D1)=9
If we can set another save point at C1, the cost of setting the save point is 2 steps (because we don't need to go all the way from A to C1; we already have a save point at B, and the path from B to C1 is 2 steps). From there, we can start at B, go to C, then from C1 to D and D1. The total cost is reduced to:1(A to B)+2(B to C1)+1(B to C)+1(C1 to D)+2(C1 to D1)=7. And this is the minimum time .

"the shortest possible time"  Time?  Do you mean you want to minimize the number non-leaf nodes visited in order to reach any leaf node?  i.e. the minimum depth of the tree.

If my guess of what you are trying to minimize is correct, then a topological sort is probably what your are looking for.

What do you mean by the cost of a savepoint? It sounds like something important has been left out.

The answer to your question really depends on how much you know about the tree ahead of time. If you know the entire tree, then you can find the optimal solution. If you have to choose your save points while you explore and you don't know anything at all about the tree except what you discover as you move through it, then you have a much different problem. How much do you know about the tree?

Yes, the tree is known ahead of time. I wonder if given the maximum allowed number of save points, how can we find the optimal solution.

If it is a binary tree, there will be a simple solution

@ravenspoint topological sort will do nothing here. This is a tree: any DFS order will be a topological sort.

In the example the optimal choice for one save point seems to be C1 not B (giving a cost of 8) instead of 9. (The second save point will then instead be at B giving the same result with two save points.) Is that a correct understanding?

You can consider using the word 'check point' which literally means exactly same as what you are trying to explain, and easily understood, by the way you dont want to use the obvious brute force right? you didnt mention it..

For each node, you can easily calculate how much you can save by making it a savepoint in O(n):

do a depth-first search and store, in each node, its depth and the number of leaf-nodes it can reach. In the example tree, node B would have depth 1, and it has 3 leaf-nodes.

the savings for making node n a save-node is depth(n)*(leaf_nodes(n)-1) (-1 because you have to reach n a first time). In the example, placing the save-point at B saves you 2 jumps.


This means that you can find the optimal single-savepoint decision in O(n) - a single pass.
At this point, I hoped that we could repeat this algorithm for each of the children, leading to a straightforward greedy approach. However,
Xellos proved that this does not work with a counter-example:
            10
           /
      4-5-6-11
     /     
1-2-3       12
     \     /
      7-8-9-13

If there is only 1 save-point, then it should be node 3, as per the above algorithm (saves 2*3=6). But if there are 2, they should be nodes 6 and 9, which save 5 each. Therefore, I would use a backtracking approach, and the cost is harder to calculate.

I see whaf you're trying, but I don't quite see how to implement it in O(n). Can you offer an implementation demonstrating that theee isn't something like a log(k) factor in there as well?

The k=1 case is correct but if you want to find multiple save points by greedily picking the best, that doesn't work. Consider a 13-node tree with 4 leaves constructed from paths 1-2-3, 3-4-5-6, 3-7-8-9, 6-10, 6-11, 9-12, 9-13. The optimal solution for k=1 is node 3 (saves 23), but for k=2 we should pick nodes 6 and 9 (saves 5+5, picking node 3 and another saves at most 23+3*1).

@btilly given N nodes, and assuming for a binary tree, N + N/2 + ... = 2N, which is in O(N). You only have to re-evaluate the children of savepoints, which should be fractions of the size of their containing trees. A more conservative estimate is O(NK).

@Xellos great counter-example. Added it, and now propose backtracking instead.

There's a O(N^3) dynamic programming solution. I doubt we can do much better since tree problems where cost is determined not by pure ancestry info, but by branching info, tend to have quadratic time complexity at best.
First off, let's treat the root and leaves as existing save points. We're just adding up to K more. The cost of a non-root save point is its distance to its nearest save point ancestor.
The DP states are: if we're considering a subtree of v (inclusive) and the nearest save point on the path from root to v (inclusive) is at depth d, what's the minimum summed cost of save points in the subtree that can be achieved by adding k of them to the subtree? Note that the savepointness of v is determined by d; we're only considering how to add save points to other vertices in the subtree.
To calculate the states for any v, first calculate all states for direct children of v. Then for each d, add child subtrees one by one and recalculate the minimum costs for all choices of total number of save points k1 added to previous child subtrees and number of save points k2 added to currently added child subtree. When adding any subtree of a child u, we consider 3 options:

u is a leaf, k2 = 0 and cost is dep(u) - d
u is a non-leaf save point, so it adds cost[u][0][k2] + dep(u) - d
u isn't a save point, so it adds cost[u][d][k2]

Pseudocode for each v, d:
tmp = [inf for k in 0...subtree_size(v)]
tmp[1 if d = 0 and v not leaf, else 0] = dep(u) - d if d = 0, else 0
for u in children(v):
    tmp_next = [inf for k in 0...subtree_size(v)]
    for k1 in 0...subtree_size(v):
        for k2 in 0...subtree_size(u):
            tmp_next[k1 + k2] = min(tmp_next[k1 + k2], tmp[k1] + dp[u][0][k2] + dep(u) - d)
            tmp_next[k1 + k2] = min(tmp_next[k1 + k2], tmp[k1] + dp[u][d][k2])
    tmp = tmp_next
dp[v][d] = tmp

The answer is dp[root][0][min(K, number of non-leaf non-root vertices)].
Why is this not O(N^4)? For each d and each child subtree of v, we loop over the size of that subtree x size of all previous child subtrees of v. This is as much as looping over all pairs of vertices which have v as their LCA. Since LCA is unique, there are only O(N^2) pairs of vertices and for each pair and all possible d, we perform O(1) operations, which gives O(N^3) amortized time, even though we're calculating a DP table with size O(N^3) using nested loops.
